# Storing sessions in mysql

Tags: database, session, cookies

I have heard about storing sessions in databases.
Are there any major advantages? I heard standard sessions do not work too well with clustered servers. 
I am hosting with MediaTemple, would this be a case for this host?

Also, if i use session_only_cookie and my user disables cookies, will the normal sessions work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advantages are a bit easier garbage collection of expired sessions, probably a bit faster session data retrieval if you have a very large number of living sessions, and potential session storage sharing between several servers, as you mentioned.

Sessions will not work for users who disable their cookies if `session.use_only_cookies` is enabled, but disabling it introduces the risk of leaking session IDs via copied URLs and is generally not recommended; also most people who disable cookies are aware of the consequences, or become aware of them very quickly.

Comment: Thanks for this. I just wanted someone to shed some light on the topic. I've been reading quite a bit about the topic and started getting confused.